# How to pass Configuration setting to donet build command on Azure WebApp git deployment?

Tags: c#, git, azure, deployment, web-config

I tried to use Azure App Service Deployment Center to set up an auto deployment using git (mine is hosted on bitbucket)

It produced an error MSB3073 on Running deployment command ...

```
[XDT] Transform file not found: D:\home\site\repository\Cairo.Portal\\web.Release.config
D:\home\site\repository\Cairo.Portal\Cairo.Portal.csproj(77,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet transform-xdt --xml "D:\home\site\repository\Cairo.Portal\\web.config" --transform "D:\home\site\repository\Cairo.Portal\\web.Release.config" --output "D:\home\site\repository\Cairo.Portal\bin\Release\net46\\web.config"" exited with code 4.
Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet publish "D:\home\site\repository\Cairo.Portal\Cairo.Portal.csproj" --output "D:\local\Temp\8d6e8bf7c33ddc9" --configuration Release
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

If I deploy directly from Visual Studio it works fine, but I am trying to set up the git auto deployment for convenience.
Please advice on what configuration I missed. Thank you

EDIT:
I've found a solution, it's to edit the deploy.cmd script under D:\home\site\deployments\tools\
There the command to publish was

```
call :ExecuteCmd dotnet publish "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Cairo.Portal\Cairo.Portal.csproj" --output "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" --configuration Release
```

Note that the configuration is fixed to Release thus didn't use the Configuration I set in my Solution Configuration Manager

I added a variable called ASPNETCORE_CONFIGURATION on the Axure webapp Configuration and changed the command in deploy.cmd as below:

```
call :ExecuteCmd dotnet publish "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Cairo.Portal\Cairo.Portal.csproj" --output "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" --configuration %ASPNETCORE_CONFIGURATION%
```

It works for now, but is there a proper way to make the deploy.cmd to use the solution config setting? instead of having to manually edit it on Kudu.